# ThanksForTheAnswer - A nice platform for users to say "thank you" to the community

Tags: app

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image: a screenshot of how the app could look like]

[ThanksForTheAnswer](https://thanksfortheanswer.dev) - TFTA - was created after seeing a colleague's excitement over using StackOverflow for the first time. He felt thankful and really wanted to at least say thanks for the user that answered him, but he couldn't do it through the platform. TFTA comes to fill this gap, by providing an easy to build easy to reach "Thank you page".

### Contact

me@vicnicius.com

Comment: When I visit the provided link I get an Heroku "Offline for maintenance" page?

Comment: ... confirmed...